# Confused with pre and postincrements inside IF

Tags: c

```
int main() { 
int x=1;
int a=2;
int b=3;
if(a++>2 && --b<3)
    x=5;
printf("%d %d %d",a,b,x); 
}
```

Shouldn't this code return 3 2 5 respectively, instead of 3 3 1?

Comment: More language tags is not better.

Comment: Haven't you thought about the fact that the behavior of this code might differ from one language to another?

Comment: If one part of the condition is false the other part might not even be executed.

Comment: Its C plain, I am sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a++>2
```

will return false, since 2 is not greater than 2 (remember, `a++` means the old value of `a` will be returned, not the incremented value). Also, `a`is now worth 3.

Since the `&&` operator is short-circuiting, the `--b<3` part will not be evaluated, so `b` is still worth 3.

The variable `x` remains unchanged because the conditional was false.

So you do get "3 3 1"

Answer (score 4):

`a++>2` is false, and because of short-circuiting, `--b<3` is never evaluated. `a++>2` is false because `a` is initially `2`, and `2` is not greater than `2`. As a side effect, though, `a` has become `3`. Because the condition was false, `x` is unchanged. Thus the final values of `b` and `x` are the same as their initial values, while `a` has been incremented.

Answer (score 4):

No. Your code explained:

```
if(a++>2) // a = 2, so 2 > 2? No. 
// So the other condition WILL NOT be checked (--b>3), because it's an && condition.
```

But, **a++** increments the 'a', **AFTER** the expression. So now:

```
a = 3
b = 3
```

The code doesn't enter into the if block. So 'x' will never be changed. Then:

```
a = 3
b = 3
x = 1
```

If you did:

```
if(++a>2 ...
```

The **++a** increments **BEFORE** the expression. So 'a' would be 3 and the if would check '3 > 2'.

Comment: Thank you man, regards from a mechanical engineering student :)

Answer (score 3):

The post-increment will be resolved first, then the comparation. That is because of the Operator Precedence Rules.

If you have two operator with different priority, the one with the greater priority will be invoked first, then the other one. If two operator have the same priority, they will be solved according to the corresponding associativity rule.

You can check operators priority and associativity rules in the next link:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence